# How to customize the automatically generated schema (or to override the Table class)?

Tags: hibernate

I use Hibernate's automatic schema generation in some tests, but it generates random names for FK constrains and no name for other constraints at all. This makes SQL exceptions a bit difficult to understand.

I am wondering is there any way to customize the output? I have already checked Dialect and the NamingStrategy, but constraint names are not generated by these. The source code of Table reveals that the format is hard-coded, so it seems I'll have to override Table. However, the Table class is also hard-coded in many places, so this seems to be very difficult. I can run loads of reg ex on the output to add the names in, but I'd really like to do it from the source.

I am using Hibernate 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to annotate?

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name="FK_YOUR_NAME")
```

Comment: Yes, this works for foreign keys, but there isn't any annotation for primary key and unique constraints (the texts are hard coded).